# Swift - A function to work out probability given defined percentages

Tags: swift, math, probability

I'm trying to understand the formula for what I wish to accomplish. Although, we cannot exactly account for this being factual, it would help give an insight into better analysis. To make it easier to understand I'll outline a scenario:

1. I buy a pack of Pokemon cards
2. Each pack of cards has 10 cards
3. The chance of me getting a Charizard is 1.1%. Whilst I have 100% chance of getting a Pokemon card, a 60% chance of getting a rare card and a 4.3% chance of getting a shiny card.

How many packs would I need to purchase to have the best % of packing a Charizard? Given my odds of 100%, 60%, 4.3% and 1.1%.

Although, this appears to be a maths question, I am trying to write a code/function for this in Swift. Where I can input the values/percentages.

Comment: What have you tried and what are the issues that you are facing?

Comment: @LeoDabus The issue I am facing is the formula, required. Am I meant to take into consideration the number of items per pack? I am currently looking at Apple's doc and reading about GKGaussianDistribution. But realistically, it's just needing the right formula.

Comment: The formula is pretty simple get a random number from 1 to 100 and check if it is within a range

Comment: @LeoDabus The percentages will be given so it could be 1.1%, 2.5% etc. It's just working out how many Pokemon pack of cards I would need to buy to give me the highest % of actually getting a Charizard.

Comment: Wait, what? If all you want to figure out is the odds of getting a Charizard, why would the odds of getting a rare card and the odds of getting a shiny card have anything to do wiht the Charizard odds?

Comment: More packs you buy, higher is the probability that you get your Charizard. There is no such thing as "best %".

Comment: This is almost entirely a math/game theory question. If your odds of something happening  are 1.1% per event, how do you figure out how much the odds go up with each repeat?

Comment: @DuncanC Surely the other chances (%)  would affect the weight of getting a Charizard, right? As I could get a Shiny/Rare instead of a Charizard?

Comment: No, they should not. I would expect them all to be independent. You could get a Charizard, a shiny, AND a rare in the same pack, right? If they tell you the  probability of getting a Charizard is 1.1%, it's 1.1%. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, buy an infinite number of packs. As the number of packs of cards goes up, the probability of getting at least 1 Charizard goes up, by very small increments, but it is never certain. (as the number of packs you purchase approaches infinity, your probability of getting at least 1 Charizard [**asymptotically**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) approaches 1, or 100%.)

I belive you figure it like this:

A probability of getting a card is 1.1% That means the probability of NOT getting that card is 100-1.1, or 98.9% (or 0.989)

Each time you get a pack, your probability of NOT getting a Charizard should be

0.989<sup>number_of_packs</sup>

(0.989 raised to the *number_of_packs_purchased* power)

After 10 packs, your probability of NOT getting a Charizard would be 0.989<sup>10</sup>, or ≈0.895 (89.5%, which means your chance of GETTING a Charizard wold be 100%-89.5% = 10.5%)

After purchasing 100 packs, your probability of not getting a Charizard would be 0.989<sup>100</sup>, or about 0.33, or about a 66% chance of getting a Charizard

Comment: Never actually thought of it like that! This makes sense. Thank you so much!